# Avoid loading data passed as props with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to pass some data to the `MainScreen` component, but in the following example, `loadData()` is being called even when I access the `/about` route.

I could pass the `loadData` function and call it from `MainScreen`, but I don't want the component to have this responsibility.

How can I load the data only when the route is accessed?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  loadData = () => {
    console.log("Loading data");
    return {
      something: 123
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <MainScreen data={this.loadData()} />
          </Route>

          <Router path="/about">
            <About />
          </Router>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is not due to use react router, but because of React architecture.

This line

```
<Route exact path="/">
    <MainScreen data={this.loadData()} />
</Route>
```

will look like something like this [after transpiling](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

```
React.createElement(Route, { exact: true, path: "/" }, 
    React.createElement(MainScreen, {data: this.loadData()}, null))
```

So code written with JSX will be transpiled to plain JS and then run. And as you may see from code above, `MainScreen` element will be created despite of whether it will be rendered by `Route` or not (`React.createElement(MainScreen, {data: this.loadData()}, null)` will be called as it is argument to another `React.createElement` which is used to create `Route` component)

Exactly your problem can be solved using [render props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func). This way, you'll pass render function to `Route` component, and it will be called only in case of route match.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  loadData = () => {
    console.log("Loading data");
    return {
      something: 123
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => 
            <MainScreen data={this.loadData()} />}
          </Route>

          <Router path="/about">
            <About />
          </Router>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  };
}
```

Here is the [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/callgetdataonlywhenroutematch-whgjm)